# Ready-to-use Open Source ecommerce using Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: open-source, cms, node.js, ecommerce, mongodb

Is there a cart system **ready for merchandise** developed in **Node.js**? I've googled a lot but found only alpha and beta projects.

More precise I am looking for something like this:

- The cart system should be **open source**
- Should be written in JavaScript and use **Node.js**
- Should be outside of beta and ready to sell
- Should have a good amount of configuration possible, something like
  Magento or at least WooCommerce
- Should have a decent **CMS**

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Additionally, take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) ("something *like A or B* is far from being sufficient here).

Comment: one of best ecommerce-framwork nodejs https://reactioncommerce.com/

Comment: I'd relax the mongo requirement unless you want to limit your scalability.